# unity поворот объекта

Tags: unity3d, математика, rotation

При повороте объекта `this.gameObject.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0,0,-90));` оси z присваевается угол `90.00001` (старт `0`). Как повернуть ровно на `90`? Вращение у меня идет зацикленное, и получается 5 "этапов" `0 -90.00001 -180 90.00001 180`.

Как убрать эту погрешность? Пробовал округлять, но без толку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Никак, это погрешность float чисел.*

Unity, как и большинство других 3д приложений, использует кватернионы вместо привычных углов Эйлера при вращении. Кватернион в случае Unity оперирует с 4 float числами, которые принимают значения от -1 до 1, а мы помним, что рядом с 0 числа с плавающей точкой в принципе не очень точные, отсюда и получаем такую ошибку.

---

Когда вы пишите `transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0,0,-90));`, на самом деле вы получаете череду преобразований:

Vector3(euler) -> Quaternion type -> Quaternion rotation -> Vector4(newQuaternion) -> transform.rotation = newQuaternion.

А для вывода в инспектор transform`а quaterion опять преобразуется в углы Эйлера:

Vector4(newQuaternion) -> Vector3(euler).

---

На самом деле это все не так страшно, да, мозолит глаза, но вы же не физически-точную модель в Unity собрались делать, такая маленькая погрешность ничего не изменит.

Выхода тут 2:

1. где эта погрешность и может что-то сломать, так это в сравнениях, выход простой - сравнивайте через `Mathf.Approximately`
2. научиться работать с кватернионами, т.к. в Unity вращения реализованы именно через них, углы Эйлера добавлены для "простоты" - большинство людей не знают, что за кватернион такой, им это просто не нужно.

Comment: Спасибо тебе большое, знал что это такое, просто не знал такую большую разницу.